# Creating an MVC helper method to add "title" to the control for a tooltip

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extension-methods

I'm creating my first MVC helper method, but can't quite get it. I want to emit the same code as the standard "@Html.TextBoxFor" but with the attribute "title" and its value taken from the model property. This is what I have so far. You can see I'm trying to just use the standard "TextBoxFor" at the end and add my own attribute to it, but that doesn't seem to be the way to do it.

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxForWithTitle<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
    return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, new { @title = metaData.DisplayName });
}
```

Specifically, I get a compile time error:

```
'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>' does not contain a definition for 'TextBoxFor' and no extension method 'TextBoxFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\DevData\JWilliams\Code\Sandbox\URIntakeMVC2\URIntake\HtmlHelpers.cs  16  31  URIntake
```

Comment: What is not working? You don't get the expected generated HTML or do you get an error?

Comment: Can't you use an EditorFor template perhaps?

Comment: @nemesv Added compile-time error message to question.

Comment: Have you referenced the namespace `using System.Web.Mvc.Html` in your file?

Comment: I have now! That got me a step closer. Now, however, when I run it, it complains that "no extension method 'TextBoxForWithTitle'" accepts the model type that that I'm trying to pass to it in my view. I'm trying to call it like I was before. Do I need to change how I call it? @Html.TextBoxForWithTitle(x => x.FormSubmitter.LastName)

Comment: Have you added the namespace where you have your `TextBoxForWithTitle` to your view? I guess it is: `@using URIntakeMVC2.URIntake`

Comment: Boy, me and my "usings" today! Thanks, nemesv. That did it. So, my code above, along with adding something like "[Display(Name = "Form Submitter Last Name")]" to a property on my model gives me tool tips! Thanks for your help. If you want to add your help as an official answer, I'd like to give you credit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [TextBoxFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) for the `HtmlHelper<TModel>` class which lives in the `System.Web.Mvc.Html` namespace.

And if you want to use an extension method you need to explicitly import its namespace with the `using` directive. So you are missing the `using`:

```
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
```

And don't forget that you are also creating an extension method here (`TextBoxForWithTitle`), so when you want to use it in your view you also need to `using` your own `TextBoxForWithTitle` methods namespace:

```
@using URIntakeMVC2.URIntake
```